# How to get Datadog Alert data through API call

Tags: datadog

I have set the threshold value to get the alert in data dog for infrastructure. Alert is coming on  data dog UI but how to get this all alert data through API call either using JAVA or python. I need only alert data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're probably looking to query the event stream which is where all alerts from monitors can be found.  The docs at https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#events-get-all are a pretty good starting place.

You'll want to query this endpoint with the proper source and tags, but this should be a starting point.  If this doesn't quite work, I'd recommend looking at pulling the details from the monitor as shown here:  https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#monitor-get-details. This may be a second option if you're unable to get the information you're looking for from the event stream.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want  all the Alert not any Extra data

Comment: for both application and Infrastructures

Comment: Yes, the event stream should be where you want to go then. You'll want to likely query every minute or so and shift your timestamps to match this window. You can then parse out any events with the alert_type ("error", "warning", "info" or "success") you're looking for. 

In the case of wanting all alerts, you'll want your sources to be filtered as `*`.  This should give you any and all events and you can programmatically filter out the ones with the appropriate alert_type.

Comment: agreed, although if all you want is the monitor alert events, you probably want `source_type_name` to be set to `alert` in addition to `alert_type` being set as `error` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: api.Monitor.get(2081, group_states='all')  .  from where i will get this Id 2081, beacuse we need to pass this id to get data

Comment: You can grab the monitor ID from the URL itself for example: https://app.datadoghq.com/monitors#1234567?group=all&live=1h the ID here is 1234567

Comment: Alert is showing warn or critical  even after agent is stopped . i mean when agent is stopped then alert should not come but even after agent is stopped  previous data is coming by calling    api.Monitor.get_all()

Comment: Can u please tell me that how can I get only Violated Alert through API call .